# Trying to override Description Horizontal List

Tags: css, slds

I'm using the `Description Horizontal List` from `SLDS`. My code so far :

```
<dl class="slds-dl--horizontal">
    <dt class="slds-dl--horizontal__label"><b>Hello1</b></dt>
    <dt class="slds-dl--horizontal__label"><b>Hello2</b></dt>
    <dt class="slds-dl--horizontal__label"><b>Hello3</b></dt>
    <dt class="slds-dl--horizontal__label"><b>Hello4</b></dt>
</dl>
```

Looking at my UI I see the first three are `inlined` but the last one is falling down to the next line. The reason behind this is because the `width` being used in `slds-dl--horizontal__label` is at `30%`. I've been trying to override the width percentage but it is not being reflected. Any idea what might be wrong?

This is my CSS:

```
.THIS.slds-dl--horizontal__label {
   width:10%;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have your CSS declared as below (notice the space between *.THIS* and *.slds-dl--horizontal__label*

```
.THIS .slds-dl--horizontal__label {
   width:10%;
}
```

From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm): Note that this is a descendant selector and it contains a space

Comment: Forgot to include the `.THIS` in my question. The space was the key! Thanks a bunch :)